# SharePoint solutions comparison

Tags: sharepoint-server, deployment, administration

I just took over a SharePoint project from a 3rd party company. It's on live for a while and I will be adding new features to the project from now on. There are 3 identical SharePoint farms for DEV / UAT / PROD environments.

The project basically consists of;

- A set of SharePoint Lists
- A set of Content Types
- A set of Workflows (all developed with SharePoint Designer)

How can I compare DEV / UAT / PROD objects to make sure that they are all identical?

Comment: As they are in different farm so you have check all objects manually I guess.

Comment: You can never be sure, unless a 3rd party tool was used to keep them in sync. I'd say spent a day sampling content and if you don't find anything worrying you, you are save to go.. *but never sure*.

Comment: How this solution is deployed. Is it farm solutions, apps, PS scripts or all modifications are done manually some how?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using TFS as a form of Version Control for this project (Assuming it is based in visual studio). TFS Express is available for small teams (up to five users) and would allow you to leverage the same code base across farms.

In addition to that, I would use jQuery and the REST API to create a web application that calls to the lists & content types pulling back the data you need. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx) has several examples of how to structure these calls.

There are no Rest API Endpoints for Workflow Associations so you would still have this requirement to fulfill.